# Sql order by < string in linq to entity framework

Tags: mysql, linq, entity-framework

how to perform this query in Linq (lambda) to Entity Framework.

```
select * from table where name like '%someString%' order by name <'someString', name
```

Let's say I have this data on server:

```
aba
baa
```

querying by '%ba%'

```
if I order by name the result will be :
aba - baa

if I order < name the result will be :
baa - aba (which is desired)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aString.CompareTo(anOtherString) < 0` is translated as `aString < anOtherString` in SQL (at least by the Sql Server provider, maybe also in MySql, hope you're lucky). So in your case it would be

```
from t in context.Table
where t.name.Contains(someString)
orderby (t.name.CompareTo(someString) < 0), t.name
select t
```

(courtesy p.campbell bumping this back to the front page).

Comment: Yep, using `CompareTo()` would generate the same results if EF can do the translation to MySQL for this operation. Gert, thanks for reminding of CompareTo()  :) http://dotnetfiddle.net/7tjRS0

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you're using Entity Framework to query a MySQL database table.

One solution would be to create an anonymous object containing your entity and its sort score. Replace `Table` with your entity of course

```
var matches = DataContext.Table
               .Where(x=>x.Name.Contains(searchToken))
               .Select(x=> new {Table = x, 
                                Score = (x.Name.StartsWith(searchToken))})
               .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Score)
               .ThenBy(x=>x.Emp.Name);
```

Here's a [.NET Fiddle demonstrating](http://dotnetfiddle.net/SOPEMx).

Comment: you understood correctly, but the query is `order by name <'someString'` and not `order by name 'someString'` notice the `<` char

Comment: it sorts by text starting with that string, not sure the complete algorithm. it's usefull to order results on autocomplete partial searches. edited question with example provided.

Comment: StartsWith is not an option because I have multiple world like : `Bart Calixto` and I want to lookup for `Calixto`. if I use like 'word%' then that won't be found.